# can't publish a Visual Studio 2010 website : The TransformXml task failed unexpectedly

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Can't publish a website. When I try to publish it to a valid FTP or a local folder, I get following error:

> Error  1   The "TransformXml" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The URI is empty.
>      at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
>      at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.TransformXml.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, Boolean& taskResult)       0   0*

How do you deal with this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this has solved my problem:
http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/03/visual-studio-2010-config.html

Answer (score 0):

Adding     `<AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>False</AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>`
 in the csproj on the right PropertyGroup fixed the problem for me.